# TypeORM production package.json

Tags: typeorm

I cannot find it in documentation, how I can run TypeORM in production? Should I use package.json script:

```
      "prod": "tsc && node ./build/index.js",
```

Is that correct? Or just use `node index.ts`?

What do you suggest, or do you have some experiences with this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run `node index.ts` directly, for this ts should be transpiled into js - with this tsc helps.

Before running on production you need to make sure that initially there are next things present:

- in your index.ts you have established connection to Database using TypeORM createConnection method
- after connection established - start server

package.json is the right place for this script: `tsc && node ./build/index.js` and now you can run this command from any places in the project. Started server will use TypeORM to query DB.

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using ts-node:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev

Then all you would need to do is:

```
"prod": "ts-node ./build/index.js"
```

I would also recommend using ts-node-dev for development:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev